# Vue.js and laravel problem with delete method

Tags: laravel, vue.js, web, axios, vue-component

Hi im new in website develpoment and i have a problem in my project(laravel, vue.js, mysql), i created the delete api and it works well when i used postman but in the Vue file when use the axios.delete it did not work ?
btw (post,get) work well.
sorry for this english.

```
<template>
<div class="table">
    <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Matricule</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prenom</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Annee</th>
    <th>Action</th>

  </tr>
    <tr v-for="etud in EtudTable" :key="etud.id">
    <td>{{etud.id}}</td>
    <td>{{etud.matricule}}</td>
    <td>{{etud.nom}}</td>
    <td>{{etud.prenom}}</td>
    <td>{{etud.email}}</td>
    <td>{{etud.annee}}</td>
    <td><button @click.prevent="Delete(etud.id)">Supprimé</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
     </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

      data(){
        return {
          EtudTable : []
        }
      } ,
      created:{

      },
      methods:{
        Delete(id) {
  axios.delete('api/Etudiant/${id}').then(function (response){
      let index = this.EtudTable.findIndex(etud => etud.id === id);
      this.EtudTable.splice(index, 1);
     });

},
getVueItems: function getVueItems() {
  var _this = this;

  axios.get('api/Etudiant').then(function (response) {
    _this.EtudTable = response.data;
  });
},

   ....
      }
    }
</script>
```

Route\api:

```
Route::delete('Etudiant/{id}', 'EtudiantController@Delete')->name('etudiant.delete');
```

EtudiantController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Etudiant;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class EtudiantController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function Delete($id){
        $etudiant = Etudiant::find($id);

        $etudiant->delete();

        return response()->json('successfully deleted');

    }

    ...
}
```

Etudiant model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Etudiant extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['matricule', 'nom', 'prenom', 'email', 'annee'];
}
```

Comment: So no errors in your webbrowser console? How about if you dd($id); at the top of your controller

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer What response do you get on your browser's console?

Comment: Can you confirm if it's not really deleted in the database? Maybe it's an issue on the frontend.

Comment: rcbgalido yes when i use postman to delete it works, so i think the problem  is in the front but where i don't know

Comment: i tried this and it works :axios.delete('api/Etudiant/'+id).then(....)
but can anyone tell me the diffrence between :'api/Etudiant/'+id   and   'api/Etudiant/${id}' ?

Comment: The answer below from Kamlesh Paul explains why `'api/Etudiant/${id}'` doesn't work, @KingJoSeph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
axios.delete(`api/Etudiant/${id}`).then(....)
```

Use backtick `` ` `` not `'`.

[Reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)